# Restrict mobile view to not occur when zoomed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webpage with responsive design.

It switches to mobile view when on mobile devices or if I switch the view on a Desktop browser to be smaller / mobile via inspect.

This is correct.

But it also switches to mobile view when I zoom to 300-400% range while on Desktop.

I don't want this to happen. When I zoom while on Desktop view, I want it to remain as Desktop view with horizontal scroll if the page goes out of view.

Is it possible to target responsive design to be only for mobile but not for zoom?

This is a React application thus trying to find a universal solution for the overall page instead of having to meddle with individual components.

Like one component might have styling like

```
.sample {
  border-radius: 2px 0 40px 0;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    padding-top: 4px;
  }
}
```

Another component might have this

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .heading {
    margin-left: 12px;
  }
}
```

I don't want to individually handle these. Just looking for a way to turn off mobile design when zoom is used on Desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

css can not detect whether user is mobile or not, you gonna need some javascript code for that. you can detect whether user is mobile or not and save it to state, and style elements according to that, therefore you gonna do some inline styling too.
detect device of user:

```
 const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
    if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      setIsMobile(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

and style elements according to that:

```
 <div style={{ padding: isMobile ? '0px' : '10px' }}>
     
    </div>
```